# How to select content by rows?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating and deleting rows dynamically, while create rows I create dropdown on the selection of dropdown the next field html changes i.e. `INPUT LNAME` .

As the rows are creating and deleting dynamically so when I add a new row and when I select the value from dropdown all the html get changes in `INPUT LNAME`. Instead only that row html in `INPUT LNAME` should get changed not all the html of al  the rows

[working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-field-hi6ji?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    rows: [{}]
  });

  const handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows[idx] = { ...rows[idx], [name]: value }; //here
    setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      fname: "",
      lname: ""
    };
    setState({
      rows: [...state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveSpecificRow = idx => () => {
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows.splice(idx, 1);
    setState({ rows });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  const [ddlSelectedid, setDdlSelectedId] = React.useState("");
  console.log(ddlSelectedid);

  const handleSelect = event => {
    setDdlSelectedId(event.target.value);
    setShow(false);
  };

  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
  const selectionContent = idx => {
    if (ddlSelectedid === "INPUT") {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          value={state.rows[idx].name}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    } else if (ddlSelectedid === "RADIO") {
      return (
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="lname"
          value={state.rows[idx].name}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    } else if (ddlSelectedid === "CHECKBOX") {
      return (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="lname"
          value={state.rows[idx].name}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>INPUT FNAME</th>
            <th>Dropdown</th>
            <th>INPUT LNAME</th>
            <th>Button</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
            <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
              <td>{idx}</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="fname"
                  value={state.rows[idx].name}
                  onChange={handleChange(idx)}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="cars" id="cars" onChange={handleSelect}>
                  <option defaultValue="INPUT">INPUT</option>
                  <option value="RADIO">RADIO</option>
                  <option value="CHECKBOX">CHECKBOX</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                {show && (
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="lname"
                    value={state.rows[idx].name}
                    onChange={handleChange(idx)}
                  />
                )}

                {!show && selectionContent(idx)}
              </td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn" onClick={handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleAddRow} className="btn">
        Add Row
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `show` property should be based on the row id to be  shown. You can set show to the specific id and check it with `showId === idx &&` instead of `show &&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add array for `ddlSelectedid` & `show`. You assigning single value in `ddlSelectedid` & `show`. When you change dropdown, that updates for all rows.

you can check working code here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-framework-hh9fe?file=/src/App.js:0-3985)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const item = {
    fname: "",
    lname: ""
  };
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([item]);

  const handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    rows[idx] = { ...rows[idx], [name]: value }; //here
    setRows([...rows]);
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setRows([...rows, item]);
    setDdlSelectedId([...ddlSelectedid, "INPUT"]);
    setShow([...show, true]);
  };

  const handleRemoveSpecificRow = idx => () => {
    rows.splice(idx, 1);
    setRows([...rows]);
    ddlSelectedid.splice(idx, 1);
    setDdlSelectedId([...ddlSelectedid]);
    show.splice(idx, 1);
    setShow([...show]);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(rows);
  }, [rows]);

  const [ddlSelectedid, setDdlSelectedId] = React.useState(["INPUT"]);

  const handleSelect = (event, idx) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ddlSelectedid[idx] = event.target.value;
    setDdlSelectedId([...ddlSelectedid]);
    show[idx] = false;
    setShow([...show]);
  };

  const [show, setShow] = React.useState([true]);
  const selectionContent = idx => {
    if (ddlSelectedid[idx] === "INPUT") {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          value={rows[idx].lname}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    } else if (ddlSelectedid[idx] === "RADIO") {
      return (
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="lname"
          value={rows[idx].lname}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    } else if (ddlSelectedid[idx] === "CHECKBOX") {
      return (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="lname"
          value={rows[idx].lname}
          onChange={handleChange(idx)}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>INPUT FNAME</th>
            <th>Dropdown</th>
            <th>INPUT LNAME</th>
            <th>Button</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((item, idx) => (
            <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
              <td>{idx}</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="fname"
                  value={rows[idx].fname}
                  onChange={handleChange(idx)}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <select
                  name="cars"
                  id="cars"
                  onChange={e => handleSelect(e, idx)}
                >
                  <option defaultValue="INPUT">INPUT</option>
                  <option value="RADIO">RADIO</option>
                  <option value="CHECKBOX">CHECKBOX</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                {show[idx] && (
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="lname"
                    value={rows[idx].lname}
                    onChange={handleChange(idx)}
                  />
                )}

                {!show[idx] && selectionContent(idx)}
              </td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn" onClick={handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleAddRow} className="btn">
        Add Row
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you explain these lines ddlSelectedid[idx] = event.target.value;
    setDdlSelectedId([...ddlSelectedid]);
    show[idx] = false;
    setShow([...show]);

Comment: when you click on handleSelect event we will change value in same row only. So, we will change value in idx index of ddlSelectedid array. and you will update state like this setDdlSelectedId(ddlSelectedid);

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: and ... is spread operator. Spread operator will create duplicate object. You can get more details about spread operator from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: few bugs are still here. when you will Remove a middle row then you can see a bug. You can fix that bug also with help of array

Comment: Remove button functionalities now not working correctly somehow

Comment: On Remove button it removes the last ```INPUT FNAME``` then ```DropDown```` and then current ```INPUT LNAME``` current remove button click

Comment: you were using wrong value={rows[idx].name} inside input tag, it should value={rows[idx].lname} , I updated code here and in link also https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-framework-hh9fe

Comment: No it still don't work it does not remove in proper ways.